# Как правильно сконвертить Set в Vector?

Tags: java

Написал такой класс, но он не работает, подскажите как правильно конвертнуть и чтобы принимал объекты любого типа. Спасибо.

```
 public class CollectionsUtils {
        public static Vector<E> convert(Set<E> set) {
            Vector<E> vector = new Vector<E>(set.size());
            for (E e : set) {
                vector.add(e);
            }
            return vector;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не работает - т.е. не компилируется? Добавьте параметр к методу:

```
public static <E> Vector<E> convert(Set<E> set) {
```

Eclipse, например, сама вам это подсказывает.

Кроме того, можно (возможно, и стоит) воспользоваться существующим решением:

```
java.util.Collections.addAll(vector, set.toArray(new Integer[0]));
```

Или схожей функциональностью от [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/).

Comment: работает. спасибо. Из-за одного метода использовать апач коллекшн... не

Comment: А вы вообще уверены, что вам нуден именно Vector? Вам обязательна его синхронизованность?

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вообще так сложно? Почему нельзя было просто ?

```
public static <E> Vector<E> convert(Set<E> set) {
    return new Vector<E>(set);
}
```

Comment: вариант

Answer (score 1):

И вообще я думаю что Vector уже считается deprecated, есть много других Collection объектов которые неплохо справляются...